# Visual Studio 2010 comment plugin for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, plugins, comments

Could you please recommend comment generator -- plugin for VS 2010 like GhostDoc for C++?

GhostDoc is perfect but works for .NET only and generate XML comments. 
I need to generate plain C-style comments for methods and classes.

Are there any such extensions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Atomineer Utils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/products.php) is a very good plug-in for Visual Studio. Single key-combo for automatically generating comments for entire blocks or even entire files based on an easily defined schema.

Comment: Thanks for it. It seems it's no way to define your own comment style; they have three predefined comment types and that's all. 
Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Are there any free products?